# All my plants have problems with the leaves and im unable to identify the exact cause of the issue

Tags: vegetables, houseplants, fruit-trees, plant-health, plant-care

I have some vegetables and fruits in my balcony. All are in pots. Unfortunately, almost all of them start to develop issues in their leaves. Yellowing, having grey dead spots, etc. Here are some photos I took :

## Plant 1 (Start Fruit) :

[image]
[image]
[image]

## Plant 2 (Egg plant) :

[image]

## Plant 3 (Bitter gourd) :

[image]
[image]
[image]

I also have orange, a small variety of orange (I don't know the English name for it) and grapes. They are doing well! Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: This looks like three different issues to me, fungus, leaf miner and ??? Voting to close as too broad.  You can edit the question to ask about one plant and ask about the others in other questions.